# grep search string and copy line from tsv to another file

Tags: bash, search, grep, csv

I have a tsv file with thousands of tab delimmited lines and I need to search for someones name and then copy the entire line to a seperate file over and over.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is vague but this should generally work:

```
grep "some-name" *.tsv > ouput
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very simple:

```
grep "someone's name" tsv-file > separate-file
```

What's the catch?  Is the name in one or two fields?  Middle initials?